# Android data binding function caching

Tags: android, data-binding

If in one `.xml` file (with enabled data binding) I execute two times the same expensive function(with the same arguments), the return of this function will be cached or it will be calculated also two times?

If it will be calculated twice, is in android a clever idea to force cache use for function executions while data binding?